# Collection.Sort(list1,new myComparable()) in mockito

Tags: java, mockito

How to mock `Collection` class?

In my class have like below

```
ArryList al=new ArrayList();
al.add("hai");
al.add("hai2");

Colletion.sort(al,new myComparable()).
```

While writing Mockito test cases for above method i got `NullPointerException`. Please suggest me how mock `Collection.sort()`.

Answer (score 2):

`Collections.sort` is a static method and it cannot be mocked. I cannot imagine why you would want to mock it but if you really need to, I suggest you move the sort part of your method to another class `Sorter` with a non-static class `Sorter.sort(List<?> list)`. Then, you can mock that class in your test.

**Update**
There exists a framework named [PowerMock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock) that can be combined with Mockito. Its documentation states to be able to [mock static methods](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage#mocking-static-method). I have never used it but you may want to give it a try.

Comment: in my service class  of one of method have collection.sort().while mocking entire method i got nullpointer exception in the place of collection.sort().